# Change class on a-element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, addclass, removeclass

I'm fairly new to Javascript, and I've run into an issue which is annoying.

I have a list containing lists. I have a script that sets the list visible / invisible on click. However, I wan't to toggle / add a class to the link, once it has been pressed.

My list looks like this

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="toggle('item1');">Click something</a>
    <ul id="item1" style="display: none;">
        <li>Something ...</li>
        <li>Something something</li>
    </ul></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="toggle('item2');">Click something else</a>
    <ul id="item2" style="display: none;">
        <li>Something more...</li>
        <li>Something something less?</li>
    </ul></li>
</ul>
```

and my script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle(id) {
        var v = document.getElementById(id);

        if (v.style.display == '') {
            v.style.display = 'none';
            v.removeClass("selected");
        } else {
            v.style.display = '';
            v.addClass("selected");
        }
    }
</script>
```

The list shows and hides as it's supposed to, but the class is not added nor removed.

CSS is like this:

```
a:link {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a.selected {
    color: #005b97;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 2px;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Best Regards
Benjamin

Comment: use `$(id).toggleClass("selected");` and dont forget to include jquery

Comment: May be this can help you,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript

Comment: @BerkerYüceer You should note that this requires jQuery and isn't ordinary vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: @RandyMarsh thats why i said ("dont forget to include jquery") at the end.. and as long as considering he already tried to use jQuery in his code that means he doesnt require "vanilla JavaScript"..

Comment: I've included jquery - forgot to mention that :/

Anyway, it doesn't work with $(id).toggleClass("selected"); However, if I use $("a")... something does happen. Sadly it affects all a-tags in the html :)

Comment: @BerkerYüceer Oops… I guess I didn't see that. :-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to do it with less code. Hoefully it does what you need it to do.

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
<li><a class="aSwitch" href="#" >Click something</a>
<ul id="item1" style="display:none">
    <li>Something ...</li>
    <li>Something something</li>
</ul></li>
<li><a class="aSwitch" href="#" >Click something else</a>
<ul id="item2" style="display:none">
    <li>Something more...</li>
    <li>Something something less?</li>
</ul></li>
```

​
**CSS:**

```
a:link {
color: #000000;
text-decoration: underline;
}

a.selected {
color: #005b97;
text-decoration: none;
padding-left: 2px;
}
```

​
**jQuery**

```
$('a.aSwitch').click(function() {
$(this).next().toggle();
$(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

See it working here: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8RNDh/1/)

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Was almost c/p-able :)

just had to add `$(window).load(function() { ... });`

Comment: You are welcome Also a shorter  **$(function(){ //jquery code here });** would work

Answer (score 5):

js does not have an inbuilt add and remove class

Try this

To add a class

`document.getElementById("MyElement").className += " MyClass";`

To remove a class

`document.getElementById("MyElement").className = 
   document.getElementById("MyElement").className.replace
      ( /(?:^|\s)MyClass(?!\S)/ , '' )`

And if you need to check if an element has a class

```
function hasClass(ele,cls) {
return ele.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)'));
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but if I try this - it adds "selected" to <ul> and not <a>. Could you please elaborate how you'd do it. Thanks for the input so far.

Answer (score 3):

There's no addClass / removeClass in vanilla JavaScript.

Either you have to use [HTML5 classList API](http://davidwalsh.name/classlist) or directly manipulate `v.className`.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("idElement").setAttribute("class", "className");
```

Comment: This would replace any other class applied to the element.

Answer (score 0):

Most easily u can add jquery addon

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Than change your code to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle(id) {
    var v = document.getElementById(id);
    $('#' + id).toggleClass("selected");
    if (v.style.display == '') {
        v.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        v.style.display = '';
    }
}
</script>
```